# How to install node and nodejs-legacy on remote Ubuntu server without internet access?

Tags: server, remote, nodejs

I have a remote Ubuntu server without any internet access.
I can access it shell and fileSystem (ssh and sftp).

How can I install it?
Is there any possible way to install it without root access?

Comment: @zwets no, this is not about packages. I've bundled all the packages I just need nodejs installed. Plus I would like to know whether root access is mandatory or not.

Comment: So your question is how to install node js without _root_ access? You may want to update your question title to reflect this. That also [already has an answer](https://askubuntu.com/q/981799/134479).

Comment: @zwets 'So your question is how to install node js without root access?' Yes :) But the answer you gave (that i've already read) isn't related to no internet access.

Comment: I think I'm lost now. Could you please edit your question to make clear what you want to achieve, and _where and how this fails_? [Be specific](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: NodeJS is a package. Anything you install is a package. How is this not answered by the suggested duplicate target?